Sharing information from one Experience Builder web app to another upon action
I have a master experience builder web app with a list of information like TYPE, ID#, link_to_child_web_app, etc.
The current workflow we use is, the user finds the entry in the list that they want more information on and clicks the link to the child web app.
In the child web app, they have to locate the same ID# they clicked in the master web app by filtering for it, which updates the widgets to only show information for that ID#.
My goal is to cut out this last step to speed up things. Instead of having to locate the needed ID# twice, I would like to set up the apps such that the appropriate ID# is filtered for by default in the child app once it is opened from the link on the master app.
Presumably, I would need to create two custom tools. One in the master app to store information from the list in a database when a hyperlink is opened. And another tool in each of the child apps to, upon opening, check to see if it was opened from the master dashboard and, if so, automatically filter all of the widgets in the dashboard to only show entries with the necessary ID#.
Does anyone know if this is possible with ArcPy or a similar tool and has anyone had any success with a similar task?
I'm using ArcGIS Enterprise version 11.1.
